# The nether has been reset after converting server and installing plugins

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server

I had a nether portal system all set up with 4 to 6 different nether portals, all leading to different areas.

I added two plugins which required switching from stock server jar to Craftbukkit jar.  The two plugins were tree assist and lockette. (I'm using the multicraft control panel for server edits.)

The nether has now reset.  Everything I built in the nether is gone.

Has anyone ever heard of this? Any ideas as to why?

I'd like to mention that this nether portal system had been working perfectly for a couple weeks now. And I'd like to emphasize that everything I placed in the nether is gone! While everything in the overworld is still fine and untouched.

Comment: I'd like to mention that this nether portal system had been working perfectly for a couple weeks now.  And I'd like to emphasize that everything I placed in the nether is gone!  While everything in the overworld is still fine and untouched.

Comment: You should edit your question to add details, rather than using comments.  Do you have a backup of your world?  What plugins?  Was the server already spigot/bukkit before the plugin installs or did you change over from a vanilla server?

Comment: Sorry, i'm new to this website. I don't know how to edit my question.  I did not have a back up sadly. (there wasn't much that was lost, so i'm not too terribly upset. I just want to know what happened.) the two plugins were tree assist and lockette.  When I uploaded the plugins I had to switch from "Default" to "Craftbukkit"  for the server Jar.  (I'm using the multicraft control panel for server edits.)

Comment: @NordicNugz directly below your question tags are 3 words in grey: share, edit, and flag. Please click edit to add these new details to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility, which is what I suspect happened, is that when you converted from stock to craftbukkit, the nether folder did not get moved properly.  When you run craftbukkit for the first time in a folder that is already a stock server, it has to make some changes.

One of those changes is moving the nether and the end region/anvil file folders into their own folders.  Your world is now contained in 3 folders.  If you stayed with the default name of **world** then the folders would be named **world**, **world_nether**, and **world_the_end**.  Originally, the world folder contained two folders named DIM-1 and DIM1.  These folders contained the region/anvil file folders of the nether and the end.  When craftbukkit is first run it should create the folder world_nether and move DIM-1 from the world folder to the _nether folder.  The same of DIM1 to the _the_end folder.  If you had looked in console on first run you may have seen something like this:

> [88:88:88 INFO]: ---- Migration of old nether folder required ----
>   [88:88:88 INFO]: Unfortunately due to the way that Minecraft implemented multiworld support in 1.6, Bukkit requires that you move your nether folder to a new location in order to operate correctly.
>   [88:88:88 INFO]: We will move this folder for you, but it will mean that you need to move it back should you wish to stop using Bukkit in the future.
>   [88:88:88 INFO]: Attempting to move world\DIM-1 to world_nether\DIM-1...
>   [88:88:88 INFO]: Success! To restore nether in the future, simply move world_nether\DIM-1 to world\DIM-1
>   [88:88:88 INFO]: ---- Migration of old nether folder complete ----

Something similar for the end folder.  Perhaps this operation failed.  If it did fail, the DIM-1 folder may still be in the world folder.

If it is:

- Stop the server.
- Download a full backup copy of your server files (do this either way and do it regularly)
- Go into the current _nether folder and rename DIM-1 to something else (ex:DIM-1_bak)
- Move the original DIM-1 folder from the world folder to the _nether folder.
- Start the server and see if the original nether is back.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense now. Thank you! Fortunately, I didn't actually lose very much.  It was just a couple of tunnels. So, i already redid what I lost (and did better)  But, i'm new to hosting a minecraft server, so this is valuable information for me!